# Phone number column not recognized as text. Adding quotes does not change the value

Tags: excel

I have a list of phone numbers and I need to add a `"` at the beginning and the end of each number so they can be read into a program.

The following method worked when I had a list of emails:

> Add quotes at the beginning and end of all the cells in a column
>
> 1. Select / highlight column
> 2. Right-click on the selection
> 3. Click on Format
> 4. Format Cells ...
> 5. Custom
> 6. Click on the Standard textbox and write `\"@\"`

But for phone numbers, Excel does not seem to recognize the numbers as text even though I change the format to Text once and then apply the above. How can I convince Excel to treat these values as normal text?

As you see in row 20, Excel even adds a decimal which, if I am to export the file to CSV, may give the destination system the wrong idea.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula: `="""" & TEXT(A1;"0") & """"`

Formula may vary by region and language, for American: `="""" & TEXT(A1,"0") & """"`

`""""` is the escaped version of a double quote.
The formula converts your number to text and then sticks a double quote before and after it.

Comment: Thank you! I had to enter a semicolon instead of a comma: `= """" & TEXT(A1;"0") & """"`. It would be great if you could clarify that as well in your answer.

Comment: I have to use semicolon aswell, but I edited my answer to have comma because american region excel uses commas in formulas. It's insane that excel's formulas are region and language based. If you were to use a different language even this "TEXT" would not be valid.

Comment: @JerMah it’s not insane, it was done to meet users requirements: **we** use the , as a separator while others wanted ; Of course you could start the argument about left & right hand drive or the number of plugs for electrical appliances or 110V to 230V etc etc

Comment: @JerMah So true! So many hours wasted troubleshooting only to realize that everything is different based on these regional settings. In fact, every little Excel assignment of mine takes much longer to finish due to this so I normally just write a program instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with flash fill.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0nuy.jpg